# Double cursor on second screen in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, cursor, osx-yosemite

Since I started to use 2 monitors with my MacBook Pro, the cursor on the second (pivot) screen is doubled - one cursor is normal arrow and under that is the second cursor which is changing (hand etc.) If I zoom the screen one cursor zoom but the other cursor remain the original size.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this? It’s kinda annoying because the cursor is always blinking on link, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Switching the resolution between `Scaled` and `Default for display` worked for me (just switching between various scaled resolutions had no effect).

[image: System Preferences: Displays]

Answer (score 0):

Shaking my mouse (moving my finger on the trackpad) really fast got rid of the second cursor for me.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the HDMI cable and reconnecting it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).